# Port-forwarding with router for local kubernetes cluster using microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, local, portforwarding, microk8s

I am trying to set up a local Kubernetes cluster using microk8s. I'm using official addons of microk8s for dns, storage, cert-manager and ingress.

I have an issue with forwarding incoming requests coming to my router to the microk8s kubernetes cluster.

When I try to access the ingress inside the cluster from my local machine via updating hosts file with the ip address of the cluster node and domain name, everything works fine. However, when i try to access it from another computer, it does not work. It looks like the router is does not forward the requests or it simply is not able to do that for some reason.

I double-triple checked my router port-forwarding configuration and it looks correct. How can i troubleshoot this issue? What might be wrong?

I am completely out of ideas as i am not an expert on networking. I would appreciate any help!

P.S. ChatGPT could not help with the issue despite so many hours of troubleshooting :)

Update: I tried to port forward incoming requests to the simple python server I started and it works so there is no issue with port forwarding on router. The issue seems to be with accessing the cluster.

Comment: Is the cluster running on your local machine? Is it running on a separate network address space? If so, you have to setup routing so other machines on the network use yours as a gateway to access the cluster.

Comment: Yes, its running on my local machine and I setup routing already as i mentioned in the post. But I do not know whether the routing works or if there is another issue..